# Confused about finding polar coordinates

Tags: polar-coordinates

I am working on this problem. [image]

I need to find the polar coordinates of point $D$ on the curve. Now since $D$ lies on the negative $y$ axis, $\theta = 3\pi/2$ and I get $r = -2$. So the coordinates would be $(-2, 3\pi/2)$. But the answer at the back of the book is $(-2, \pi/2)$. Am I missing something? The book is "Precalculus: A Problems Oriented Approach" by David Cohen (6ed.)

Comment: Actually, $D$ lies on the positive $y$-axis ($\theta=\pi/2$) and $\cos(2\theta)=-1$ there...

Comment: Also: Please, try to make the titles of your questions more informative. E.g., *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.*
From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: @gebruiker, how can you say that D lies on positive y-axis ? Confused there. I will try to follow the guidelines for posting.

Comment: It's somewhat of a joke, to put things in perspective. If you put $\theta=\pi$ into a polar function, you don't necessarily end up on the negative $x$ axis. If your function is such that $r(\pi)<0$ then you end up on the positive $x$ axis.

Comment: To get a better understanding, try answering the following: In which order will the points $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$ and $E$ appear as we draw the curve, starting at $\theta=0$. Where I define $E$ as the point on the curve with maximum $y$ value

Comment: Sorry gebruiker, but still don't get it. I will have to go back and review some more. If I check Wolfram Alpha, output for $\theta$ from $0$ to $\pi$, the order seems to be A, D, B, C. But without looking at the plots for different ranges of $\theta$, I find it hard to understand.

Comment: Then calculate $r(\pi/2)$ by hand and try to explain how it can end up on the negative $y$ axis.

Comment: It's all in the following: Do you understand that $(r;\theta)=(-r;\theta+\pi)$.

Comment: Actually I found [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k5dtjlgIiwY) video from Mario's Math Tutoring Youtube Channel and he describes easier way of working with negative $r$ values. He explains that the method usually taught in schools is confusing. And I agree with him. With that understanding, all my confusion has gone away. Thanks gebruiker.